# How to change function call text color of Python in PyCharm?

Tags: python, pycharm

Is there a way to change function call text color of Python in PyCharm?

After searching preference menu, I only found function definition color option in Python. There is a function call color option in Lanuguage Defaults, But It not work for my Python code.

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you can go to the :

`settings > color Schemas > python` and select `Function call` .
so in the **right** side, unchecked `Inherit values from` and select a custom color `Foreground` and `Background`.

[image]

Comment: Which version your PyCharm is? I don't find Color Scheme but only Colors & fonts.

Comment: I using `PyCharm 2018.1.4 (Professional Edition)`